# MVC3 web site on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

When I try to deploy an ASP .NET MVC 4 web app on IIS 6, I get the error saying

**Access to the web.config is denied.**

Identity of the app pool of the web site : **Network Service**

The folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ *appname*  has **full Control** access by Network service. But I am confused whether this permission gets applied recursively.

How can I get the site working ?

**Screenshot of the error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you check the directory security of the website, see if it is set to anonymous.  If it is, grant the IISUSR read access to the directory.

If it is windows authentication or some other method, and the .Net is set to impersonate, you will need to grant them access too.

HTH

Si

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Application Pool setting as Default pool or  .Net Frame Work Version :4.0

Comment: THis is set to 4.0 framework. You can see in the screenshot that it is version 4 that is used